# How to link GPS trackers in android?

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocation, tracking

for example taxi applications and bus tracking applications. How do you get the real time location of the vehicle? Is the link made to the driver's smart phone as it connects to wifi or is it using the IP address? How does it work

Comment: There are so many different tracking systems. Can you narrow down the problem you are having?

Comment: That is what I am not sure about exactly. If you have an android taxi application. Say for example you booked a taxi, it should show you how far your taxi is and its real time location on a map as it is moving towards your desired destination. Now how do you do that ? track the taxi on the map and its movement.

Answer (score 0):

**just tracking through SMS or MAIL mean.** you need to do something like this

```
static private Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sendSMS("123456", "your location");
        if (!stopped) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
        }
    }
};

public void start() {
    handler.postDelayed(task, initialDelay);
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

**or If you wants to make your app for more people you need these things done first..**

1. a Server
2. native application

in native application you need to get your location through location service function then and send that through [HTTPClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

just google it... you ll get ideas

Comment: So what you're saying is that in the example above i should use the driver's phone to find the location of the bus ? meaning that on every vehicle that uses this application, the location service will be linked directly to the driver's phone ? the driver's phone will get the location through the location service function and then send that through HTTPClient which will instantly update it on the UI ? need some clarification on the method please, im not used to developing such complex apps.

Comment: i can tell you the flow of my idea in that.

Comment: i can tell you the flow of my idea in that. you need 2 functions in app. if you want to use server...1.function to be sending your lat and long. 2.receiving whatever data from server. then in server side you need a function to receive lat and from various device. and do what ever processes you want to do with lat and long in server side and send the result to device (2rd app function)... just google abt it to get idea to develop functions like that